# Cakephp Rest Get header

Tags: cakephp, httprequest, request-headers, requesthandler

I'm trying to get header content from a json post request.
But I can't seem to find a method for it in the requesthandler...

`print_r($this->request);`  doesn't show anything useful.
I've tried

```
$this->request['head'];

$this->request['header'];

$this->request->getHeaders;
```

None of which work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the headers using:

```
 $this->request->header('User-Agent');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeRequest::header

Comment: Is there an option to get all of the headers at once? Can't find a solution in the documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 2 doesn't have

> $this->request->headers()

or something like that.

You can use the PHP function `getallheaders()` instead.